# MAMP PRO won't execute PHP files?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, php, mamp

For some reason, PHP files display as plain text in the browser when I browse locally via MAMP PRO.

I looked through the PHP settings and there doesn't seem to be anything there that would affect this:

[image]

I ran `phpinfo();` and it's showing version 5.4.10 running fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you fixed it, put the solution in as an answer so others can realize this was fixed without reading the entire question

Comment: have you checked to see if php.so is loaded in httpd.conf?

Comment: @CanadianLuke Thanks, I added the solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out I had an .htaccess files in the parent directory, with the following line in it:

`AddType x-mapp-php5 .php`

Removed the file and now PHP executes properly. I guess I don't need to have this .htaccess file on my local machine.